# Push notification not working in TestFlight external testing

Tags: ios

I need help with external beta testing my application on test flight. Application have push notification and after upload etc push not working. Appliacation have provisioning profile for distribusing and server have both distribusing and developing.
Any ideas ?

Comment: are you using GCM push services or working with apple native apns?

Comment: I use syncano push service

Answer (score 0):

Can you check when you are uploading your ipa on iTunesConnect, which provisioning profile is selected.
[provisioning profile : XC*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXnLv.png)